# Idea of Hensel's Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, hensels-lemma

$$P(x, y)=0 \tag {1} \\ \text{ where }P(x, y) \in \mathbb{Q}[x, y]$$ 
[image]

How do we know that $(1)$ has a solution in a $\mathbb{Q}_p$ ?

We will apply Hensel's Lemma.

**Idea:** we begin from an element of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, that has some identities $(a_1)$.

Then we create a sequence of values $a_1, a_2, \dots$ that approaches the root, that we finally find.

Hensel's Lemma gives us the most important algebraic identity of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

$$$$

At the beginning of the idea, we have that:

*"we begin from an element of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, that has some identities $(a_1)$"*

What identities are meant??

Comment: You wrote the "idea" so you should explain that! If you are taking this wording from another source then you really should say what source it is.

Comment: I found it in my notes... @KCd

Comment: So you are asking others to make sense of what you wrote down yourself. In that case I think the right person to talk to is whoever was giving the lecture those notes were based on. Better yet, just read accounts of Hensel's lemma in many books or online notes to learn what it is and how it is used in examples, since as written your wording about Hensel's lemma unfortunately makes no sense.